# Search Bar xcode swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift, search

Написал код для поиска значений в таблице, при нажатии на search bar  таблица пропадает, но нужное мне значение не появляется.

В чем может быть проблема?

**Обновление**

```
var find: [List] = []
var searchResult: [List] = []

let context: NSManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var detailViewController: MainVC? = nil
var frc : NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

var searchController: UISearchController!

func getFetchResultsController() ->NSFetchedResultsController {
    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: listFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    return frc
}

func listFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest{
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest (entityName: "List")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "item", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    return fetchRequest
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    frc = getFetchResultsController()
    frc.delegate = self
    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {}
    if let split = self.splitViewController {
        let controllers = split.viewControllers
        self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? MainVC
    }
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    let numberOfSections = frc.sections?.count
    return numberOfSections!
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchController.active {
        return searchResult.count
    } else {
        //return find.count
        let numberOfRowsInSection = frc.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
        return numberOfRowsInSection!
    }
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {      
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)       
    let search = (searchController.active) ? searchResult[indexPath.row] : frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! List
print(search)
//Configure the cell..
cell.textLabel!.text = search.item
let qty = search.qty
let address = search.address

cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Dukan Sayi: \(qty)\(address)"
return cell
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    if searchController.active {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let managedObject : NSManagedObject = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject

    context.deleteObject(managedObject)

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {}
  }
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController:        UISearchController) {
    if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
        filterContent(searchText)
         print(searchText)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
func filterContent(searchText: String) {
   searchResult = find!.filter({ ( a: List) -> Bool in
        let nameMatch = a.item.rangeOfString
(searchText, options:     NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)  
        return nameMatch != nil  
        })
}
```

Comment: Может хоть кто идею предложит? )

Comment: Идей нет. Хочешь, плюсик поставлю?

Comment: минимальный пример вашей проблемы, который скомпилируется очень бы помог. а еще я бы вам предложил найти туториал по этому вопросу и посмотреть как это реализуется.

Comment: проблема такая что функция searchResult не находит нужные данные в core data, соответственно не выводит их в таблицу (фильтр). Примеры в основном касаются array ев, как я понимаю с базой немного по другому и примеров нормальных я не нашел.